What does a "sharp read" mean?
I've seen this phrase in a book. Can you explain what "sharp read" means here? Can you suggest a synonym for it?

Thankfully, we now have this book to give us a clear view and sharp
read on this essential subject.


This is the sense of sharp that means astute and insightful. The OED gives:

Acute or penetrating in intellect or perception. Keen-witted and alert in practical matters, businesslike, smart.

A read on something is a take on it, an impression.

And nounal read as in 'It's a good read'.

@EdwinAshworth Oh I thought it was sharp that was the puzzle here, not merely a read.

It's not a normal expression ('[a book] giv[ing] us a sharp read'); the normal fixed phrase is '[this book] is a good read'.

@EdwinAshworth This is the read that means a take, an impression.

On reflection, you're probably right, but 'a sharp read' is so far from being a collocation that I'd say interpretation is far from straightforward.
